# htaccess rewrite only first query

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i m new to .htaccess. I have many searches, nothing works well.

I wanted to convert my dynamic page to static.

```
test.com/?gender=pop&rows=1&page=2 to
```

```
test.com/gender/pop.html?rows=1&page=2
```

also work for

```
test.com/?gender=pop to
```

```
test.com/gender/pop.html
```

simply only rewrite first query. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gender/(.+)\.html$ /\?gender=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PS: this will work with any gender. (EX: gender=pop, gender=male, gender=female, gender=123, ...) Please let me know if you need it to be more specific.

Comment: Wow, the code works perfectly just exactly i want :D, i m surprised the code was that simple. im trying direcly applying regex but doesn't work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you like to keep dynamic parameters ?
Test something like this :

```
RewriteRule ^gender/([a-z]+)\.html\?rows\=([0-9]+)\&page\=([0-9]+)$   gender=$1&rows=$2&page=$3  [L]
```

I hoe this help,
Mike

Comment: thanks mike, but the code doesn't work. i tried search anywhere but couldn't find how to deal with '&'.

i just want to make my main landing page more visible to SE, to reduce user confusion since variable after ?gender is constantly changing and may contain more than 2 var. :)